# What circuit, using a 3.3V or OPEN signal (as the switch) can switch between a different signal and ground?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I believe a Mux would possibly do what I want here, but I'm not sure that's the best solution. Also, I think most mux don't handle open circuits as input signals, but I could be wrong. Can I use an AND gate? Again, I'm not sure how that handles open circuits?

All of the scenarios:

1. Signal A is positive (3.3V), Signal B is positive (3.3V), Output then equals Signal B (3.3V)
2. Signal A is positive (3.3V), Signal B is OPEN, Output is Grounded
3. Signal A is OPEN, Signal B can be anything, Output is Grounded

[image: Circuit Block Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

You can likely use an AND gate and input pulldowns on each input (i.e. a resistor from signal A to ground, and a resistor from signal B to ground). A value of 10 kOhm is probably reasonable.

This causes the scenarios to become:

1. Signal A is positive (3.3V), Signal B is positive (3.3V), Output then equals Signal B (3.3V) (and equals Signal A, and equals 3.3v for that matter)
2. Signal A is positive (3.3V), Signal B is <strike>OPEN</strike> weakly grounded, Output is Grounded
3. Signal A is <strike>OPEN</strike> weakly grounded, Signal B can be anything, Output is Grounded

which matches the behavior of a single AND gate. You'll need to find a chip with one or more 3.3v-compatible AND gates, and also pull down the inputs of unused gates (if the chip contains more than one gate) to avoid picking up electrical noise.